# routing problem of the fault-tolerant routing algorithm added in the Noxim simulator

Tags: routes, mesh, simulator, topology, fault-tolerance

I added a fault-tolerant routing algorithm named "GRADIENT" to the Noxim simulator (https://github.com/davidepatti/noxim) according to the Noxim_Tutorial PDF, the routing algorithm was successfully added, but I couldn't get results from the files in Config_Example. What is the problem with my routing algorithm?

[image]

This is the article I used: "https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/6385394"